# Vb.net List(of Object) has object entries with same value on the rulenumber field. Need to merge those objects into one

Tags: vb.net, object, merge

I am new with the vb.net enviroment and I need some help to figure out if there is an easy way to merge objects from the same List (of objects) that have the same value on a field ( in this case it will be the rulenumber).

I don't have a code ready i just need first to figure out if there is a way and how to proceed in order to built this functionality.

So the plan is that i have a list(of objects) which contains many entries of objects with fields like rulenumber amount count sign.
In that list i have many entries that have the same rulenumber. And i want to make a new list (of objects) and combine all the objects with the same rulenumber field in one entry.

Please advise.

Comment: Can be done, with a little graft...

Comment: that little graft is what i am lookin for :)

Comment: why make a 3rd list?  just add the things from List2 which are not in List1.  The hard part is collisions where both contain the same object but have a different value.  It also sounds like maybe the whole thing could be avoided by using a Dictionary(of T) so that one collection could accumulate all values to start with.

Comment: Stupid answer...just don't allow more than one entry with the same rulenumber?  When adding items, iterate over the list and update the object already there if you find a match.  Or use a Dictionary() as Plutonix suggests, but use rulenumber as the key.

Answer (score 0):

That will be 6 beers, thanks :-)

```
    Class myCustomList
    Property objectList As New List(Of mycustomobject)

    Class mycustomobject
        Property thisIsmyProp As String
    End Class


    Public Sub _add_object(objectToAdd As mycustomobject)
        For i = 0 To objectList.Count - 1
            If objectToAdd.thisIsmyProp = objectList(i).thisIsmyProp Then
                'this object exists... merge it in
                objectList(i) = objectToAdd
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next

        'object was not found, add it..
        objectList.Add(objectToAdd)
    End Sub

End Class

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim mylistOfObjects As New myCustomList

    Dim myNewObject As New myCustomList.mycustomobject
    myNewObject.thisIsmyProp = "12345"

    mylistOfObjects._add_object(myNewObject)

    myNewObject = New myCustomList.mycustomobject
    myNewObject.thisIsmyProp = "56789"

    mylistOfObjects._add_object(myNewObject)

    myNewObject = New myCustomList.mycustomobject
    myNewObject.thisIsmyProp = "12345"

    mylistOfObjects._add_object(myNewObject)

    Debug.Print(mylistOfObjects.objectList.Count)

End Sub
```